# SublimeText RegReplace Highlighted Text Only

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am trying to use the Sublime Text Plugin [RegReplace](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace/blob/master/docs/usage.md) package so I can highlight a line of text and replace spaces with dashes.

- **Goal**

  - `Hello My Name is Jesse`, Highlight, `CTRL + .` replaces with:
  - `Hello-My-Name-is-Jesse` -- for the purpose for saving time creating markdown links.

**Currently Working, But Runs Entire File**

I would really like this to only replace the text I have highlighted wit a hotkey, is this possible?

I have this in `reg_replace_rules.sublime-settings`

```
{
    "replacements": {
        "replace_spaces_with_dash": {
            "find" : "(\\s)",
            "replace": "-",
            "greedy": true,
            "case": false
       }
    }
}
```

Here is my `User Hotkeys`

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+."],
    "command": "reg_replace",
    "args": {"replacements": ["replace_spaces_with_dash"]}
},
```

However, this replaces the **entire file** with spaces. I am missing something I hope, I am not sure the scope. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `"selection_only": true`

Comment: No dice with that guy, bummer! I saw it defaults to the highlighted text, so it says, i tried this:             `"find" : "^(\\s)$",
            "replace": "-",
            "case": false,
            "no_selection": false`

I guess more figuring out is required